# Possible to programatically specify Windows Explorer display columns and column order?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have a program that creates a large and complex file structure from information in a database.  The folders have cryptic names so to assist the user I add a Title attribute for each folder (using desktop.ini).  When the Title column is the first column of the listing in Windows Explorer the display is perfect.

The problem is that each user must understand how turn on the display of the Title column and reorder the columns so that Title is the first column, otherwise they see only the cryptic name of the folder.

Is there anyway I can have my program write information into the root folder (or anywhere else) that will configure each copy of Windows Explorer, by default, to present the custom view of the folder that I want?